# hdfs: "No such file or directory" on existing file

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hortonworks-data-platform

'ls /' on hadoop gives the following output:

```
# hdfs dfs -ls /
Found 18 items
drwxrwxrwt   - yarn               hadoop          0 2019-05-20 09:22 /app-logs
drwxr-xr-x   - hdfs               hdfs            0 2019-05-15 10:07 /apps
drwxr-xr-x   - yarn               hadoop          0 2019-05-15 09:37 /ats
drwxr-xr-x   - hdfs               hdfs            0 2019-05-15 09:23 /atsv2
drwxr-xr-x   - test               hadoop          0 2019-05-16 16:56 /data
...
```

However, when I try to delete the /data folder I get:

```
# hdfs dfs -rm -R /data
rm: `/data': No such file or directory
```

or ls:

```
# hdfs dfs -ls /*data*
ls: `/data': No such file or directory
```

So somehow my /data folder is corrupt and I cannot delete or use it anymore. **Does someone know how I can delete it?** I've tried with both hdfs and test user. Also, if I create a new /data folder I have 2 coexisting ones.

I've created this original /data folder using a .sh script that looks as follows:

```
#cat createdata.sh
hdfs dfs -mkdir /data
hdfs dfs -chown -R test:hadoop /data
```

I've created this script on linux, but edited it via scp (mobaXterm) on windows with sublime. Might it have to do something with strange characters?

Anyhow, It would be nice if I can get rid of this corrupt /data folder.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to remove it myself using:

```
# hdfs dfs -rm -R hdfs://cluster/dat*
' to trash at: hdfs://cluster/user/hdfs/.Trash/Current/datacluster/data
```